# how to add attrs to many fields on a form?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms

I've got a really big ModelForm and want to implement [Ketchup jquery validation](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/). I have to add a `data-validate=` onto every form field I want validated and it's getting laborious to say the least.
At the moment I have something like this:

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AuthorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['data-validate'] = 'validate(required)'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['data-validate'] = 'validate(required, email)'
        self.fields['is_alive'].widget.attrs['data-validate'] = 'validate(minselect(1))'
        self.fields['telephone'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'telephone'
        self.fields['telephone'].widget.attrs['data-validate'] = 'validate(required)'
```

But with about another 20 fields to go I'm wondering if there's an easier way to be adding these attributes to the fields I want validated. (Not all fields have to be validated, they can be blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not even knowing what Ketchup is, I clicked on your link and found an example on how to do it w/o attributes on the fields, that is, by passing it in to the ketchup() method:

"Right after the options (empty here {}) we pass in an object. Use the key to declare the jQuery selector on which fields the validations in the value are processed. Validations declared like this don't need the validate() indicator."

```
$('#fields-in-call').ketchup({}, {
  '.required'    : 'required',              //all fields in the form with the class 'required'
  '#fic-username': 'username, minlength(3)' //one field in the form with the id 'fic-username'
});
```

If you're looking for alternative libraries, I would opt for jQuery.validate

Comment: I see. That is pretty cool. However if I do that then I still have to add a class attrs to every field on the `def__init__ right`? This would land up being exactly the same amount of work. `self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['data-validate'] = 'validate(required)'` would become `self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'required'`

Comment: No, you don't *have* to add a class to the field.  You can use any selector you want, that example just used a class for the required fields so he didn't have to list out names or ids of every field he wants to require.  You could use `{'input[name=asdf], input[name=asdf2]' : 'required' }` instead of `{'.required' : 'required'}`, for example

Comment: You could also set up validation rules in a data structure and loop over the data structure or something...